# Admin Category Product count shows wrong value

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8

[image]

Admin Category Product count shows wrong value when Is Anchor is yes.

Please help.

Comment: In Magento, if a category is set with Is Achor Yes, then it will include all products of its sub-categories in the frontend. Maybe it can be the reason.

Comment: "Animal Crafts" under not sub-category.i have tried Is Achor Yes and No Select.

Comment: if others 10 products include then showing 14 count but products showing 10.

Comment: Try to reindex and flush the cache once.